# Breakdown of basic multivariable calculus help

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am just starting on multi-variable calculus now and I am a bit stuck on a (very) basic explanation for a question:

$$  \int\limits_0 ^\infty \int\limits_y^\infty 6e^{-(2x+3y)} dx\ dy$$
$$  = \int\limits_0^\infty 3e^{-5y}\ dy$$
$$=3/5$$

I don't understand how we jumped from line 1 to line 2, and if I tried to integrate on X I could only reach this $-3 e^{-2x}\ dx$.

So perhaps anyone can show the detailed breakdown of the equation above.

Comment: You should *evaluate* your $x$ integral by inserting the limits of integration.

Comment: $\left. -3 e^{-2x}\right|_y^\infty = 3e^{-2y}$.

Comment: @mjw, but the answer shows $-5y$ instead of $-2y$?

Comment: Looks like your question was answered.  $\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty 6 \exp(-2x+3y) \,dx\,dy = \int_0^\infty 3\exp (-2y)\exp(-3y) dy = \int_0^\infty 3 \exp(-5y)\,dy \cdots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as I believe you're already aware, you evaluate each part from the inside out, i.e., you have

$$\int\limits_0 ^\infty \int\limits_y^\infty 6e^{-(2x+3y)} dx\ dy = \int\limits_0 ^\infty\left(\int\limits_y^\infty 6e^{-(2x+3y)} dx\right) dy \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Inside those brackets, you treat $y$ as being a constant as you're *only* integrating wrt $x$. Thus, you get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\int\limits_y^\infty 6e^{-(2x+3y)} dx & = \left. 6\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{-(2x+3y)}\; \right\rvert_{y}^{\infty} \\
& = 0 - (-3)e^{-(2y+3y)} \\
& = 3e^{-5y}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note with the integration, you get $-3e^{-2x-3y}$, not $-3e^{-2x}$ as you stated, i.e., you should not have dropped the $-3y$ part. For the outer integration, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty}3e^{-5y} & = \left. 3\left(-\frac{1}{5}\right)e^{-5y}\; \right\rvert_{0}^{\infty} \\
& = 0 - \left(-\frac{3}{5}\right)e^{0} \\
& = \frac{3}{5}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help John! This helps tremendously as my understanding about which parts to be treated as constants is very shaky now :(